# Разные времена глаголов в предложении

Tags: глаголы, времена

Есть ли какие-то ошибки в формулировке данного предложения: "Спасибо, что остаёшься, чтобы увидеть, кем я становлюсь." Допустимо ли подобное написание?
Если неверно, то какие конкретно правила в русском языке на это указывают?

Comment: Кажется, всё хорошо. Не вижу поводов сомневаться.

Comment: Здесь причина озвучивается за кого-то. Это лишь догадки человека, не реальная причина, как по грамматике. Это не очень правильно. Из-за этого режет слух.

Answer (score 1):

Да, можно, никаких проблем.

Можно даже: *спасибо, что останешься, чтобы быть тем, кто увидел, кем я становлюсь.* В звучании: спасибо, что останешься, чтобы быть тем "кто увидел, кем я становлюсь". Запятые, самый простой способ разбить фразу на логические блоки, запятая - пауза, можно усложнить пунктуацию для лучшего понимания, но в речи любая пунктуация будет может быть выражена просто в паузах покороче(запятые) и подлиннее(тире).

В русском языке есть реальное время - хронология, а есть время посылок - последовательность изложения предположений слева-направо, условное время.

Задача читателя соотнести хронологию и ожидание, чтобы создать причинно-следственную цепочку событий.

Он останется - имеет желание остаться.

Далее - чтобы быть тем, кто увидел - когда он останется, он может стать тем, кто видел/увидел, то что будет дальше.

Кем я становлюсь.

Так как нельзя сказать, что было случится раньше, он увидит или "я стану" - то скорее всего эти события произойдут одновременно, однако, мотивация ставится чуть до, перед условием. Но это уже вкусовщина.

*Спасибо, что останешься, ведь я становлюсь, а вот кем - ты скоро увидишь.*

*Ты скоро увидишь, кем я становлюсь, если будешь тем, кто остался.*

Ты скоро увидишь, кем я стал// если ты будешь тем, кто остался.
Тут две фразы связанные условием, то есть лучше начать с условия если:

Если ты будешь тем, кто остался - условия события в будущем, которое, если произошло, то есть "он - остался". Тогда -

Ты скоро увидишь, чем я стал - после выполнения условия ты увидишь, кем я стал - увидишь законченное действие - кем я стал. В какой момент он стал, в условии нет, может быть уже стал, а может еще нет, может станет только когда другой увидит это.

Хотя, конечно, такие формы предложений, как ребусы.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146993/discussion-on-answer-by------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.